# How to get text between two nodes using Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I would like to get all the text between two nodes (`<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>` and `<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>`) as one line.
The text is stored in the elements `w:instrText`.

```
...
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:b/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:b/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"/>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:b/>
          <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:instrText>block</w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r w:rsidRPr="00516DAB">
        <w:rPr>
          <w:b/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:instrText>[255]</w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:b/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"/>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:b/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
      </w:r>
...
      <w:r w:rsidR="00516DAB">
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
      </w:r>
      <w:r w:rsidR="00516DAB">
        <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"/>
      </w:r>
      <w:r w:rsidR="00516DAB">
        <w:rPr>
          <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:instrText>block</w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r w:rsidR="00516DAB" w:rsidRPr="005630D5">
        <w:instrText>[2]</w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r w:rsidR="00516DAB">
        <w:instrText xml:space="preserve"/>
      </w:r>
      <w:r w:rsidR="00516DAB">
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
      </w:r>

...
```

I tried using `//w:r[preceding::w:r[w:fldChar[@w:fldCharType="begin"]]][following::w:r[w:fldChar]]/w:instrText` but I'm not getting what I need:

[image]

I want to get this result:

```
block[255]
...
block[2]
...
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: "I would like to get all the text between two nodes": which two nodes exactly? Which version of XPath exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance with XPath 3.1 for your sample and the path expression

```
let $begins := //*:r[*:fldChar/@*:fldCharType = 'begin']
    ,$pairs := $begins ! map { 'start' : ., 'end' : following-sibling::*:r[*:fldChar/@*:fldCharType = 'end'][1] }
    ,$text := //*:instrText
return
    for $pair in $pairs
    return string-join($text[. >> $pair?start and . << $pair?end])
```

you would get a sequence of two strings, the first being `block[255]`, the second being `block[2]`.

A different but similar way is to use use the `for-each-pair` function:

```
let $text := //*:instrText
return for-each-pair(
  //*:r[*:fldChar/@*:fldCharType = 'begin'],
  //*:r[*:fldChar/@*:fldCharType = 'end'],
  function($s, $e) {
    string-join($text[. >> $s and . << $e])
  }
)
```

I had to use the namespace wildcard `*` on any selection as you didn't show any namespace declarations for the input document.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Martin Honnen. Preferably XPath version 1.